# Html form input in place of python django forms

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I am writing an application with django. I know how to implement the django forms but what I want to do really is to have an html input input with type text or email or password and save the input to database or link it to the form.py

**form.py**

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    publish = forms.DateField(widget= forms.SelectDateWidget)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            "title",
            "content",
          ]
```

**views.py**

```
def create(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        messages.success(request, "Post created")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    template = 'create.html'
    return render(request,template,context)
```

**html**

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <p>
      <input type="checkbox" id="test5" />
      <label for="test5">Red</label>
      </p>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit post">
  </form>
```

Comment: just access it `request.POST.get('test5')` I dont understand the question maybe

Comment: I am saying instead of "title" in form.py I would like to use ` <input type="text" name="title" value="title">` and the input would still submit into the database @JoranBeasley

Comment: @King you want to replace `{{ form.as_p }}` with individual html input tags?

Comment: exactly @BillF.

Comment: Well you can do exactly that if you really want. Did you try? What happened? But there's not really a good reason to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Well just use this:

**HTML**

`<input type='text' id='title'>`

Insert following code under `if form.is_valid()`

**views**

`title = request.POST.get('title')`

`post = Post(title=title)`

`post.save()`

---

Comment: would I have to include the post in my render?  reference my view.py

Comment: Nope. Just write this code inside the `if form.is_valid():`

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML form, 
1. In the form tag, give the action as a URL
2. Then in urls.py, specify a view corresponding to that URL 
3. Now, in your views.py write the view.
To get specific fields from your html form, you need to give the field an id in your template. Then in your view you can access particular fields by the ids.

Also, do specify the method=GET/POST in the HTML form, if you are using POST and would like to take only POST queries, then in your view just add `if request.method=='POST'`

Hope this helps!

Comment: can you break it down for me plese

Comment: My urls.py  `urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^private/$', private),]
 My views.py  `def private(request):
  if request.method =="POST":
   name = request.POST['namev']
   return render(request, "nonuser.html", {'name':name})
 else:
  return render(request, "404.html")`

Comment: @King my html `<form action="/posts/private/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
   <input type="text" id="namev" name="namev"><br>
   <input class="btn-warning" type="Submit" value="Submit" id="cli">
  </form>`